# How to exclude all folders except one?

Tags: git, bitbucket

I'm using git for developing sites and there is one thing that keeps bothering me. For sites which are on shared hosting (cpanel) I must create .gitignore in home directory and then in that file put every folder except one, "public_html". Is there any other way that I can exclude every folder in home directory except public_html, dynamic way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `!` to exclude patterns in your .gitignore file

E.g.:

```
*/
!public_html
```

This excludes all directories (even those you will create after) except public_html.

Comment: but OP wants to make it in *dynamic way*

Comment: Can you post example please?

Comment: sure, try the example I added